# problem creating admin panel option for custom extension magento

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, admin-panel

I am trying to create a Custom slider extension which has option of change settings and uploading images from admin panel I followed many tutorial available online but nothing has worked So can Anyone help in this problem to create admin option for my slider. Here is the file which I have coded now

```
Code for my app\etc\modules\Sequester_Custommodule.xml file
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Sequester_Custommodule>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Sequester_Custommodule>
    </modules>
</config>
```

And code in my app\code\local\Sequester\Custommodule\etc\config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Sequester_Custommodule>
            <version>0.1.0</version>    <!-- Version of module -->
        </Sequester_Custommodule>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <custommodule>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Sequester_Custommodule</module>
                    <frontName>custommodule</frontName>
                </args>
            </custommodule>
        </routers>
         <layout>
            <updates>
                <custommodule>
                    <file>custommodule.xml</file> <!-- Our layout file name-->
                </custommodule>
            </updates>
         </layout>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <custommodule>
                <class>Sequester_Custommodule_Block</class>
            </custommodule>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

And code for app\code\local\Sequester\Custommodule\controllers\IndexController.php

```
<?php
class Sequester_Custommodule_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

}
```

And code in app\code\local\Sequester\Custommodule\Block\Custommodule.php

```
<?php
class Sequester_Custommodule_Block_Custommodule extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    public function myfunction()
    {

        echo "hello World";

    }
}
```

And code for my app\design\frontend\rwd\default\layout\custommodule.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/jquery.bxslider.css</stylesheet></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>customslider/jquery.bxslider.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>customslider/slider_custom_script.js</script></action>
        </reference>
    </default>
    <cms_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="custommodule/custommodule" name="custommodule" template="custommodule/custommodule.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </cms_index_index>
</layout>
```

And in my Template file I called the slider images statically from skin folder but I want to give an option of uploading images from admin panel and this images will store in database table and then I want to fetch this images to used for slider .

I am first time trying to build a extension So please anyone can help me in any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
Firstly I will recommend you to use this blog.
It will make your base strong.
http://www.pierrefay.com/
 Secondly for reference purpose try this code in etc/system.xm
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <config>
        <tabs>
            <namespace_Modulename translate="label">
                <label>namespace uniquename Request</label>
                <sort_order>100</sort_order>
            </namespace_Modulename>
        </tabs>
        <sections>
            <Modulename_options translate="label">
                <label>Settings</label>
                <sort_order>200</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                <tab>namespace_Modulename</tab>
                 <groups>
                    <messages translate="label">
                        <label>Config Fields</label>
                        <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                        <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>                
                    </messages>
                    <messages translate="label">
                        <label>uniquename Request Options</label>
                        <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                        <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        <fields>
                            <uniquename_owner>
                                <label>Sender Email</label>
                                <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                                <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                            </uniquename_owner>
                            <Request_tag_line>
                                <label>Request tag line</label>
                                <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                                <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                            </Request_tag_line>
                            <uniquename_option>
                                <label>Enable/Disable</label>
                                <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                                <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_enabledisable</source_model>
                                <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                            </uniquename_option>
                        </fields>
                    </messages>
                 </groups>
            </Modulename_options>
        </sections> 
    </config>
```